# Como passar um valor da Textbox para DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

Como passar o que está escrito dentro de uma `TextBox.Text` para um `DataGridView`?
e como salvar o que esta no `DataGridView`em um arquivo `.TXT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Apos Responder notei que a pergunta foi editada no meio tempo e a tag C# Removida deixando apenas VB.net, tomei a liberdade de [converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) os codigos que escrevi em C# para Vb assim deixando as 2 versões

Para acessar o valor do *TextBox* basta usar o comando que você mesmo descreveu *TextBox.Text*
Ex:

C#

---

```
String A = TextBox.Text;
//A = Texto do TextBox
```

VB

---

```
Dim A As [String] = TextBox.Text
'A = Texto do TextBox
```

Para o *DataGridView* é simples, você precisa somente atribuir onde deseja,
Ex para Primeira linha e primeira coluna:

C#

---

```
DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = TextBox.Text;
```

VB

---

```
DataGridView.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = TextBox.Text
```

Sendo *Rows* as Linhas e *Cells* as colunas, se deseja percorrer se *DataGridView* pode fazer da seguinte forma:(Tambem pode utilizar o Foreach mas preferi o While para melhor entendimento)

C#

---

```
 int L = 0;//Linhas
 int C = 0;//Colunas
 while (DataGridView.Rows.Count > L)
 {
    C = 0;
    while (DataGridView.Columns.Count > C)
    {
      DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = TextBox.Text;//Altere o valor a ser recebido para oque desejar
      C++;
    }
    L++;
 }
```

VB

---

```
Dim L As Integer = 0'Linhas
Dim C As Integer = 0'Colunas
While DataGridView.Rows.Count > L
    C = 0
    While DataGridView.Columns.Count > C
        DataGridView.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = TextBox.Text
        'Altere o valor a ser recebido para oque desejar
        C += 1
    End While
    L += 1
End While
```

E para converter o *DataGridView* para um .txt como perfeitamente descrito [Adam White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2529063/adam-white) Nesta [Pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311535/writing-to-a-text-file-from-datagridview-in-c-sharp-windows-form) pode utilizar de um 'hack' copiando toda as informações utilizando uma função nativa de copia do *DataGridView* ao invés de percorrer ele todo

C#

---

```
private void SaveDataGridViewToCSV(string Filename)
{
    // Se quiser que os nomes das colunas tambem sejam copiados utilize EnableWithoutHeaderText como abaixo;
    dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithAutoHeaderText;
    // Seleciona todas as Celulas
    dataGridView1.SelectAll();
    // Copy (seta para o CTRL+C)
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());
    // Paste (Pega o CTRL+V e converte para um arquivo)
    File.WriteAllText(Filename,Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.CommaSeparatedValue));
}
```

VB

---

```
Private Sub SaveDataGridViewToCSV(Filename As String)
' Se quiser que os nomes das colunas tambem sejam copiados utilize EnableWithoutHeaderText como abaixo;
dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithAutoHeaderText
' Seleciona todas as Celulas
dataGridView1.SelectAll()
' Copy (seta para o CTRL+C)
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent())
' Paste (Pega o CTRL+V e converte para um arquivo)
File.WriteAllText(Filename, Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.CommaSeparatedValue))
End Sub
```

Comment: valeu pela resposta, da uma olhada no perfil, to enroscado agora em outra questao kkkk